# No output returned from plugin in centreon when using Python PyRfc library

Tags: python, linux, monitoring, nagios, pyrfc

I have written a skeleton for python script for centreon. The problem is that the script works fine until I import the pyrfc library, which is the key for this script.
Without this library, centreon returns me a green OK message which is fine.

Once the library is there, it returns No output returned from the plugin. If I run the script through the OS under the user centreon-engine it works fine even with the library. I have the latest version of pyrfc and it works fine because I use it in other scripts, it just doesn't work in the centreon UI. My command is: **python3 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/SCRIPTS/test.py** (working fine from OS).
As far as the code is concerned, it is syntactically fine. Seems like some error in centreon or something.

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- set chmod 777 on the script
- change the owner to centreon-engine
- run the script on the OS under the user centreon-engine - works
- reinstall pyrfc library
- checked Python versions

My Code:

```
#!python

__author__ = 'xxxx'
__version__ = 0.1

import os
import time
import pyrfc  # If I remove this line, it works.
from optparse import OptionParser, OptionGroup
import logging as log
import argparse
import subprocess


os.environ["NWRFCSDK_INCLUDE"] = "/usr/local/sap/nwrfcsdk/include"
os.environ["NWRFCSDK_LIBS"] = "/usr/local/sap/nwrfcsdk/lib"
os.environ["SAPNWRFC_HOME"] = "/usr/local/sap/nwrfcsdk"

# Initialize parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--destination", help="Define RFC destination.")

# Read arguments from command line
args = parser.parse_args()


def main():
    """ Main plugin logic """

    with open('/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/SCRIPTS/output_rfc.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        integer = int("".join(str(x) for x in lines))
    if integer == 0:
        gtfo(0, "OK - destination {} reached.".format(args.destination))
    elif integer == 2:
        gtfo(2, "CRITICAL - destination {} does not exist.".format(args.destination))
    elif integer == 3:
        gtfo(1, "WARNING - {} is illegal destination type 'G'.".format(args.destination))
    else:
        gtfo(2, "CRITICAL - destination {} unreachable.".format(args.destination))


def gtfo(exitcode, message=''):
    """ Exit gracefully with exitcode and (optional) message """

    if message:
        print(message)
    exit(exitcode)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar problem, the answer is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. I created a wrapper in bash where at the beginning I put the export of this variable and call the Python script, then it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

### ======================================================================= ###
###                               FUNCTIONS                                 ###
### ======================================================================= ###

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/nwrfcsdk/lib/

check_destination() {
  output=$(python /usr/lib/centreon/plugins/check_rfc_destination.py -a $1 -s $2 -c $3 -u $4 -p $5 -d $6) # Wrapper needed because of PyRfc library.
  if [ $output -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OK - destination $6 reached."
    exit 0
  elif [ $output -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "CRITICAL - destination $6 not reached."
    exit 2
  elif [ $output -eq 3 ]; then
    echo "WARNING - destination $6 does not exist."
    exit 1
  elif [ $output -eq 4 ]; then
    echo "WARNING - illegal destination type (only destination type 3 supported)."
    exit 1
  fi
}

### ======================================================================= ###
###                     SCRIPT EXECUTION START HERE                         ###
### ======================================================================= ###

if [ $# -lt 6 ]
then
    echo "Missing parameters! Syntax: $0 host sysnr client username password destination"
    exit 3
fi


check_destination "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"

### ======================================================================= ###
###                         END OF SCRIPT                                   ###
### ======================================================================= ###
```